# SharePoint Add-In Without "Basic Information about the users of this site" Permission

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, sharepoint-addin, app-permissions

I am developing a SharePoint Add-In to be published into the Office365,
When I install the Add-In into my Office365 account, it shows that my Add-In is asking for the following permission:

> "Let it access basic information about the users of this site"

I don't see any setting in the `AppManifest.xml` that requires this kind of permission.

So my questions are:

1. What kind of user information my Add-In is entitled to access, if
   the user has trusted my Add-In ?
2. How can I update the Add-In in
   order to have it not asking for this kind of permission ?